# Is it possible to bind to a value in Properties.Settings.Default?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, properties.settings

Is it possible to bind to a value in Properties.Settings.Default in a way that will keep my UI current with the value stored there?

I have a class:

```
public class FavoritePlayer
{
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return wpfSample021.Properties.Settings.Default.FavoritePlayer.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            wpfSample021.Properties.Settings.Default.FavoritePlayer = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In my XAML, I have a resource:

```
    <local:FavoritePlayer x:Key="fvPlayer"/>
```

and a binding:

```
    <Label DataContext="{DynamicResource fvPlayer}" Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
```

What I would like is for the data-binding to update any time the property is changed. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conveniently for you, `ApplicationSettingsBase` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` so you just need to subscribe to `PropertyChanged` on `Properties.Settings.Default` and raise your own `PropertyChanged` in response.

Comment: Sch-weet! (These extra characters for rent.)

Answer (score 0):

You need your properties to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in order for bindings to recognise when the property value changes.

Comment: In order for my properties to raise notification, they would need to know when the default property they're reading changed. That brings me full-circle.

Comment: @Jekke: See Rick's answer regarding that.